# Why do dpi settings over 96 screw up my site?

Tags: css, dpi

I noticed that when the dpi is set high than 96 to like 120 my site gets messed up using either Firefox or IE7. The CSS basically breaks. Anyone know how to fix this?

[Link to web-site](http://www.iaddesignandstudio.com)

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The site uses a fixed-size layout, but mixes the units `px` and `pt`. When changing the dpi of your screen, the relative size of these units changes,  ie the site is broken by design.

What you should do:

- don't use `pt` for screen layouts - `pt` is for printing only
- read up on liquid layouts and the relative unit `em`

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a fix that can *prevent* anything happening if a user has adjusted their Windows DPI setting.  Altering Windows to 'large fonts' mode, or setting it to a DPI setting other than the default, affects all layout in IE.

However, this should never cause a site to massively break.  A few things shall be slightly misaligned, perhaps, due to rounding of values.

The site you've pointed to indeed does break quite massively when the font size is changed - for instance, change the default font in the browser (or set Firefox to "Zoom Text Only").  Text from the buttons completely leaves the buttons and starts hovering elsewhere.

It looks like the main cause of this, at least with the buttons across the top, is that the whole row of buttons is single background image and the text inside them are floated elements which match up with the background image only at a given font size - any adjustment to their size and position and they become out of whack with their background.

When designing, always change the zoom setting (in IE7 and Firefox) and the font size (eg in Firefox using "Zoom Text Only") and make sure that those things that do change in size, don't break the site.  In some conditions, things specified in "pt" will scale while things specified in "px" won't.

*How you could fix it*

It's clear that you've designed everything to be a certain size in pixels, including the header and all the buttons/tabs.  If you want to do this, declare the header DIV to be position: relative, and position the H1, H2, and UL inside it absolutely, using pixel values (relative to the containing div).  Remove the margins, padding etc from the DIV to simplify.  Specify widths, heights and top margins of the LI elements using pixels.

*What I would do*

Normally, I would build things like this to be flexible, so that if for some reason a person had really big fonts enabled on their browser, it would stretch nicely to handle it.  That isn't really possible with your background images, because they are build especially for one given size only.  So I'd have a repeatable background on the header, and I'd do each background for each button separately.  Obviously, this is going to be more work.